# File './mysql-bin.index' not found on MySql startup on OSX 10.5

Tags: mysql, osx-leopard

I did a manual setup for the installation of MySql 5.5 on mac OSX 10.5 instead of using .dmg package installer.
After following all the installation steps when I started the sql server with sudo mode I got the following error and the server did not start.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: File './mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
110808 21:22:12 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I cannot find ./mysql-bin.index file anywhere in my /usr/local/msql directory.

Can anyone tell how to get around this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is permissions of this folder `/usr/local/msql`. Change the permissions with:

```
chown -R mysql /usr/local/msql
```

Then restart the MySQL server.

Answer (score 3):

This probably means mysql deamon has not got permissions to write to the data directory.

Even if you start mysqld_safe as root, the mysqld deamon will likely (depending on configuration) start as non-root (mysql for example) user. That user needs to have read write permission to various directories including data directory, log directory, run directory etc...

Answer (score 0):

This means you have binary logging enabled. Is this something you need?
It is usually required for the replication process or as a backup perhaps, otherwise everything works fine without it.

You disable it by commenting the *log-bin* line. The path for the index file is specified through the *log-bin-index* parameter under the [mysqld] section in my.cnf configuration file.